# Add Property to javax.peristence Entity

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, properties, netbeans6.8

I right click into the editor of the Entity class.
then select Insert Code but do not see the Add Property box.

I want to add a birthday property which must be annotated with the javax.persistence.Temporal annotation to mark the property as date field to the underlying database table.

I am unsure how to use the Netbeans 6.8 IDE to add this??

Answer (score 2):

> I am unsure how to use the Netbeans 6.8 IDE to add this??

Your best option is to use your keyboard and your fingers to add it yourself :)

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private java.util.Date birthday;

public Date getBirthday() { return this.birthday; }

public void setBirthday(Date birthday) { this.birthday = birthday; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Insert Code > Add Property is a feature of Netbeans 6.9. Do you have the option to download the latest version of Netbeans? That should solve the problem. Otherwise you may simply write the code yourself.